# How to use Facebook Javascript SDK to get user's info, and do I store it locally?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web app where I'd like to let the user log in with Facebook, not only to support Facebook Comment threads, but to allow me to pre-populate a form the user fills out. (For example, I ask the user to fill out a from that includes fields for their name and birthday; if they're logged in from Facebook, I'd like those fields to be filled in for them already.)

My app is written in PHP. I see that Facebook suggests using the pure-Javsascript SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/). I see the steps to log in the user and confirm their identity, but once they're logged in, how do I get their user data to pre-populate my form? Do I keep a copy in my local database, or do I just ask Facebook for that info every time the user comes to the form?

I don't need perfect code as the answer here-- I'm just looking for some steps in the right direction. What pieces of the SDK do I need to put together? What will my PHP code be responsible for vs. what Facebook's SDK does for me already?

Comment: Have you looked at [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed like this-

1. Create an app, add Javascript SDK, add login code. Refer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/).
2. Modify the login code a bit. Replace `FB.login()` with -

   ```
   FB.login({scope: 'email, user_birthday'});
   ```

   Not every details can be fetched by default, but only the basic info. For other info you have to add permissions in your code (as I've mentioned) that user will authorize. To see the list of the permissions, go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and click on button *Get Access Token*
3. After the user authorizes your app, `testAPI()` function is called. So after success, your code will start from here; where you can add the code to fill the details on the form automatically
4. You do not require to keep any database. After successful login, simply make the `API` calls to fetch any required details and set the text of the fields of your form. For eg:

   ```
   FB.api('/me', function(response) 
   {
      alert(response.name);
      alert(response.birthday);
   });
   ```

You can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me) to test the API results.

I would suggest you to read the basics from the [Developer's Site](https://developers.facebook.com/) and follow these simple steps, its not so complicated.